# Action required: Update your app to comply with Google Play Permissions policy

Tags: android, android-permissions, google-play-console

As per this link https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303 we should remove SMS and CALL_LOG permissions from manifest.

I have third party payment SDKs which are using SMS_RECEIVE permissions, but i have removed them from manifest, also merged manifest don't have it.I have used below code for that,

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"
        tools:node="remove" />
```

My question here is, do i also have to remove runtime permission code from JAVA file ?

Thanks a ton

Comment: Yes, You have remove this one otherwise you can submit a form to google which explains why you need this permission on your app.

Comment: I have removed it from manifest, from Java ? because Google mentioned only manifest?

Comment: My understanding is if it isn't in the manifest the runtime permission code will never work, but I could be wrong.